# How to deploy telegram java api

Tags: java, api, telegram

How can I deploy and run this API https://github.com/ex3ndr/telegram-api. I installed gradle but throwing the following exception:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteQuietly(Ljava/io/File;)Z

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteQuietly(Ljava
/io/File;)Z
        at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.filesystem.services.GenericFile
System.<init>(GenericFileSystem.java:89)
        at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.filesystem.services.FileSystemS
ervices.createFileSystem(FileSystemServices.java:43)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
       ......
```

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: which version mismatch?